How can i detect Jailbreak or Rooted device in my flutter app?
I am creating a app where i want to detect Rooted /Jailbreak device which is required for security.
And also if user device developer mode on.How can i detect and test this in my flutter app. Please anyone help me with this....

Just so you know-  there is no 100% way to do this.  There's a variety of libraries that will attempt to do it, but nothing is for certain.  You're better off actually writing your app to be secure than to count on those libraries.  Especially on Android, where the entire OS is open source and they can always just hack the kernel itself to do whatever they want.

But how does bank apps able to detect developer mode..

Mostly they don't.  It's not really a security risk, as the person with the phone is accessing his own account info.  There are libraries that will attempt to do this, but if someone wants to get around it they can and will.  It's a speed bump, not something you can rely on.

For detecting root and developer mode on Android and jailbreak on iOS, use this root_checker_plus.
Sample code from the link above:
import 'package:root_checker_plus/root_checker_plus.dart';

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  androidRootChecker();
  developerMode();
}

if (Platform.isIOS) {
   iosJailbreak();
}

Future<void> androidRootChecker() async {
    try {
    rootedCheck = (await RootCheckerPlus.isRootChecker())!;
  } on PlatformException {
    rootedCheck = false;
  }
  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    rootedCheck = rootedCheck;
  });
}

Future<void> developerMode() async {
  try {
    devMode = (await RootCheckerPlus.isDeveloperMode())!;
  } on PlatformException {
    devMode = false;
  }
  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    devMode = devMode;
  });
}

Future<void> iosJailbreak() async {
  try {
    jailbreak = (await RootCheckerPlus.isJailbreak())!;
  } on PlatformException {
    jailbreak = false;
  }
  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    jailbreak = jailbreak;
  });
}

